# faster way to extract video frames to pixels on mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, quicktime

I'm reading large video files, frame by frame, and hoping there is a faster way to get pixel buffers.

For those codecs which are supported I'm using AVFoundation APIs and then for the remainder (e.g. DNxHD) I'm using Quicktime techniques.

Here's a simplified version of my AVFoundation based approach.
Is there some API I have not noticed, or some attribute I could set to speed things up?

```
AVURLAsset  *myAVURLAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:@"blahblah" options:nil];
AVAssetTrack * videoTrack = [[myAVURLAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetReader *movieReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:myAVURLAsset error:nil];
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB) forKey:@"kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey"];
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput * output = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:videoTrack outputSettings:videoSettings];
[movieReader addOutput:output];
[movieReader startReading];

bool atEnd = false;
while (!atEnd) {

    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [output copyNextSampleBuffer];
    if (sampleBuffer)
    {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
        uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

        // ...do lots of stuff with pixel data
        // ...release and tidy up sampleBuffer etc

    }
    else{
        atEnd = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which bit is slow? `copyNextSampleBuffer` or "do lots of stuff with pixel data"? For the former, you can decode at a lower resolution or in yuv, for the latter you can use the GPU to do lots of stuff with pixel data.

Comment: "...do lots of stuff" is efficient, the bulk of the time is spent extracting the pixelBuffers. Lower resolutions make little to no difference, which I can appreciate, since it probably needs to decode the entire frame before scaling it down.

Comment: So how long is the extraction taking?

Comment: extraction time depends heavily on codec and original resolution. a 14min 1080p P-JPEG takes about 4min to extract every frame to a pixelBuffer. So a full length feature could take over half an hour.

Comment: What kind of timings do you get with a yuv pixel format? e.g. `kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8`

Comment: no significant difference.

Comment: So you're getting 3.5x realtime decoding. The iPhone needs to be able to do 1080p@120fps to play back its 1080p slow motion recordings, so 4x should be possible. Maybe changing codecs/encoding parameters you can get that? At 720p you should be able to get 8x realtime decoding. Otherwise you might be bumping up against a hardware limit.

Comment: frame size doesn't make a huge difference but codec really does. I've found some gains using GCD to read an h.264 file in 4 pieces concurrently, but the gains disappear when you test P-JPEG or DNxHD - In fact it's slower to decode those codecs in 4 "concurrent" tasks.

Comment: I only just realised we were talking about a mac and not iphone. that performance seems really poor!